# Helper method to start background task for ASP.NET and Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, task-parallel-library

I have a library that is consumed by both ASP.NET Web API's, and a Windows Service.  The goal is to create a helper method that will determine if it's hosted within an application pool, and use the `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` else use `Task.Run` to execute the task.

Will the following work as intended?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Hosting;

/// <summary>
/// Queue a new task execution based on application environment.
/// </summary>
public static class BackgroundTaskHelper
{
    public static void StartBackgroundTask(System.Action action)
    {
        // Determine if application is running within application pool.
        if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
        {
            // We are running within an application pool; qeueue the action so that it's presence is known to ASP.NET
            HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(c => action.Invoke());
        }
        else
        {
            Task.Run(action);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there perhaps a better manner of accomplishing this?

Comment: why can't you use `Task.Run()` for all the cases

Comment: If it's running within context of an application pool, I understand that it will run the risk of being terminated on recycle, as the identity isn't aware.  Using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` allows the application pool to know it exists, and it will await a certain amount of time on recycle (I believe 30 seconds) to complete execution.  Reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you're truly worried about the task being killed off early due to the application pool recycling, then don't put it in ASP.NET. Put it in its own Windows service and communicate to it through a message queue, such as Azure Message Queues or RabbitMQ, perhaps via [MassTransit](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/index.html).